# Extremely slow WiFi speeds on Lubuntu 19.04?

Tags: networking, 19.04

Recently reinstalled Lubuntu 19.04 on a fresh SSD as the old one failed. However, with the updated versions of Lubuntu, I am getting extremely slow WiFi speeds. This was not an issue on the previous install of 17.10. Upon doing some research I found several posts about intel WiFi adapters on 18.04, however my chipset, obtained from lspci, is a Ralink RT5392 chipset so solutions about intel adapters didn’t help. Verifying on other machines in the house that internet speeds are normal, issue only exists on Lubuntu machine. Any suggestions?

EDIT: and now it seems to be unreliable on showing the networks as available, sometimes the network icon disappears and needs a hard reboot, etc. Odd because it’s a fresh install as of a few hours ago with a fresh image as of today.

Answer (score 1):

If WiFi was working great on 17.10 but not so good on 19.04, then maybe you should go back to using 17.10 to verify it's still working fine in 17.10. This would rule out hardware/environment (such as a microwave oven being used nearby, bluetooth devices, or USB 3.0 hard drive) being changed somehow to cause the issue.

After that, perhaps try some intermediate version like 18.04 to try to pin-point when the WiFi got broken. Using the closest two versions where one works great and then other is slow, start looking around to see what is different between the two versions. Did the WiFi kernel module used get changed? If so, can you get 19.04 to work well by switching the kernel module for WiFi back to the one that was working well in previous distribution version?

If it's the same kernel module being used, then maybe you could try installing older Linux kernels on 19.04 back to the kernel version that works. When you can finally pinpoint the closest two kernel versions that work/don't work, you can then do a source code diff between those kernel versions and try to figure out what the developers did that made your WiFi get real slow. Then you can report on the Linux Kernel mailing list or contact the developer that made the offending change and tell them what has happened.